# Show ribbon bar "Documents" in WebPart page

Tags: 2010, web-part, ribbon, visual-web-part

I have created a `WebPart`. It consists of some HTML / JavaScript code for filtering a document library and a `ListViewByQuery`-`WebPart` for showing the results.
Is it possible on this `WebPart` Page to show the `ribbon` bar "Documents" as in a standard document library when selecting a document in the results area (`ListViewByQuery`-`WebPart`)? 
I've already googled a lot, but I find only results like this one to blend in the `ribbon` bar itself:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
    if (elem != null) {
                    var dummyevent = new Array();
                    dummyevent["target"] = elem;
                    dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
                    WpClick(dummyevent);
    }
}, 2000);
```

or

```
var wp = document.getElementById("_wpSelected");
if (wp != null) {
//switch to second webpart (the list)
wp.value = "MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2";
//call the ribbon for this webpart
SelectRibbonTab('Ribbon.Read', true)
}
```

Or is it possible by using another `WebPart` for displaying the results?
Thanks for any hint.